# How to connect python to orcacle 11g using cx_oracle

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to an enterprise oracle DB using cx_oracle.  This worked under a previous installation (32 bit python) but no longer works with new 64 bit python.  I am using python 3.6 64 bit.   Any help would be appreciated.

```
import cx_oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='uid', password='pwd', dsn='dns')
```

The error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH environment variable (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (other platforms) for other installations of Oracle. If you're on Windows, do a search for OCI.DLL as sometimes it gets placed in places you wouldn't expect to find it! Note as well that your Oracle client must be 64-bit if you are using 64-bit Python. You cannot use your original 32-bit Oracle installation!

Comment: Thanks.  I did find the oci.dll, in a very odd place.  Where should it be - in my Python directory?

Comment: I checked the Oracle version.  I have 12c 12.1.0.2 64 bit production installed

Comment: The install instructions http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows are worth checking.

Comment: Make sure the OCI.DLL that can be found first in the directories noted by the PATH environment variable is the one you want (12.1 64-bit).